# recorrer un objecto con Angular 5

Tags: json, angular5, object

tengo lo siguiente,
recibo datos en formato JSON de una base  en firebase utilizando el siguiente codigo:

```
  constructor(db: AngularFirestore, private modalService: BsModalService) {
    db.collection('usuarios').valueChanges()
             .subscribe( ( data: Taxista[] ) => {

             this.taxistas = data;
             console.log('data->' + JSON.stringify(data));

    });
}
```

en el HTML utilizo *ngFor para recorrer el json:

```
 <div class="list-group">
  <a href="#"  *ngFor="let taxista of taxistas" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <strong> {{ taxista.nombre }} </strong><br>
```

este es el formato JSON que recibo de firebase:

```
[
{
"1": {
  "demandado": "JOSE CARLOS PIÑOL PLANA",
  "direccion": "Barlovento 1, Real Solare.",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018-05-01 00:00:00",
  "id_expediente": "1",
  "lat": 20.6075857,
  "lng": -100.3773038,
  "status": "Inicio",
  "tipo_juicio": "1"
},
"2": {
  "demandado": "JUAN MANUEL BELMONTE HERMIDA",
  "direccion": "Barlovento 1, Real Solare",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018-06-14 00:00:00",
  "id_expediente": "2",
  "lat": "",
  "lng": "",
  "status": "",
  "tipo_juicio": "1"
},
"3": {
  "demandado": "JORGE AVILA BERRIO",
  "direccion": "Barlovento 1, Real Solare.",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018-05-01 00:00:00",
  "id_expediente": "3",
  "lat": "",
  "lng": "",
  "status": "",
  "tipo_juicio": "1"
}
}
]
```

Primer problema es el Id del JSON (es incremental), aveces pueden ser mas datos, como puedo recorrer esto en el HTML ?, yo me imagino algo como esto {{ taxista[id].direccion }}

Comment: Veo un problema: no es un array lo que recibes... o mejor dicho: es un array con un único elemento que tiene como claves (nombre de atributos) números

Comment: El comentario de @PabloLozano es de mucha utilidad para cuando hagas estas cosas... Un ngFor va iterar sobre cada ítem del array, pero tu array tiene un solo ítem, y eso va depender de dos cosas: o tu base de datos está mal planteada o tu volcado de datos tiene un error...

Answer (score 1):

EL JSON que estás creando en firebase, debería tener el id dentro del objeto, porque ahí lo que tienes es un array de tamaño 3, con estos valores [1,2,3], en el cual cada valor dentro suyo tiene un taxista, el formato que deberías tener es el siguiente:

```
[
  {
  "id": 1
  "demandado": "JOSE CARLOS PIÑOL PLANA",
  "direccion": "Barlovento 1, Real Solare.",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018-05-01 00:00:00",
  "id_expediente": "1",
  "lat": 20.6075857,
  "lng": -100.3773038,
  "status": "Inicio",
  "tipo_juicio": "1"
   },
  "id": 2
  "demandado": "JUAN MANUEL BELMONTE HERMIDA",
  "direccion": "Barlovento 1, Real Solare",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018-06-14 00:00:00",
  "id_expediente": "2",
  "lat": "",
  "lng": "",
  "status": "",
  "tipo_juicio": "1"
   },
  "id": 3
  "demandado": "JORGE AVILA BERRIO",
  "direccion": "Barlovento 1, Real Solare.",
  "fecha_asignada": "2018-05-01 00:00:00",
  "id_expediente": "3",
  "lat": "",
  "lng": "",
  "status": "",
  "tipo_juicio": "1"    
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`*ngFor="let taxista of taxistas; let i = index"` y podrías recorrer el json de la siguiente manera: `{{ taxista[i].direccion }}`.Ésta podría ser una manera.